# Problema com recursividade e ponteiros

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro, recursão

Estou com dificuldade para solucionar a seguinte questão:

> Faça uma função recursiva que permita somar os elementos pares de um vetor de inteiros, você deve utilizar ponteiros para percorrer o vetor

O meu código não está efetuando os cálculos corretos da condição `if` da função `somarpar`, ele ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int somarpar (int vet[], int n){
    int i=0, h=0, *pont=vet;


    for(i=0; i<n; i++){  

    if((pont[i]%2) == 0){

             h = pont[i] + somarpar(pont, n-1);

             }
        } return h;  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int somarpar(int vet[], int n);

    int vetor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int *p=vetor, z;

    z = somarpar(p, 10);

printf("a soma dos numeros pares eh: %i\n", z);

    system ("pause");
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro antes de ir para a resposta eu gostaria de dizer que seu programa teve vários "errinhos", então antes de tudo eu gostaria de aponta-los só para você saber onde errou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /*  Você não utilizou nenhuma função desta biblioteca, não precisava
                        ter incluido-a  */

int somarpar ( int vet[], int n )
{
    int i = 0, h = 0, *pont = vet;  /*  seu exercico diz para usar ponteiro, logo não deve
                                        usar o i para controlar o indice do vetor, e sim
                                        aritimética de ponteiro */

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )   {   /*  Você esta utilizando uma chamada recursiva, o que por si
                                        só já é um loop, for desnecessario, é aqui que faz o seu resultado
                                        sair maior do que o esperado.  */
        if((pont[i]%2) == 0)
        {
            h = pont[i] + somarpar(pont, n-1);
        }
    }

    return h;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])   /* você não utilizou nenhuma das duas variaveis, logo não deveria te-las aqui   */
{
    int somarpar(int vet[], int n); /*  declarou a função novamente, e além de tudo dentro da função main
                                        NÃO FAÇA ISSO!.  */

    int vetor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int *p=vetor, z;    /* não precisava fazer este ponteiro para o vetor   */

    z = somarpar(p, 10);

    printf("a soma dos numeros pares eh: %i\n", z);

    system ("pause");
                        /* esqueceu do return 0;    */
}
```

Levando em conta o enunciado que pede para fazer uma função recursiva e também usar ponteiro para andar no índice do vetor.

Primeiro devemos entender o que o exercício quer dizer com  **"você deve utilizar ponteiros para percorrer o vetor"**, você deve entender que, o que este exercício deseja de você, é que você utilize aritmética de ponteiro para percorrer o vetor, ou seja, sem usar uma variável i por exemplo, só com ponteiro.
Para fazer isso é simples, basta você saber que um vetor comum é de certa forma um ponteiro, e também basta você entender como que um vetor funciona, e como que é o calculo que o computador faz para percorrer o vetor.

Então vamos lá, quando você declara um vetor de qualquer tipo por exemplo e deseja percorre-lo, o que até o momento você faz é um loop onde você inicia uma variável qualquer (ex: i) em zero e depois no final a incrementa com um, mas no meio do código você faria algo do tipo `vet[i]`, certo, então o que realmente ocorre quando você faz isso é o seguinte, `vet[i]` é equivalente a `(tipo*)(vet + i)`, note que você faz um casting para o tipo de ponteiro do seu vetor, e depois soma o seu vetor com o índice que você deseja acessar.

Exemplo, vamos supor que você deseja fazer o somatório de um vetor de inteiros qualquer, você tem duas maneira de fazer:

normal:

```
for ( i = 0, somatorio = 0; i < tam; ++i )
        somatorio += vet[i];
```

ou

Utilizando aritmética de ponteiro:

```
for ( ptrVet = (int*)(vetor), somatorio = 0; tam > 0; --tam, ptrVet = (int*)(ptrVet + 1) )
    somatorio += *ptrVet;
```

Ambos como eu acho que você pode notar são a mesma coisa, a diferença é que um omite a aritmética de ponteiros que o computador faz.

Bom no outro pedaço da questão ele pede para que você faça uma função recursiva, ou seja, neste caso não é para você utilizar `for`, `while` ou `do while` para fazer o loop, e sim recursividade.

Como você utilizou na sua função eu irei considerar que você já sabe como uma função recursiva funciona, mas mesmo assim darei uma breve explicação bem simplificada.

Uma função recursiva é uma função que chama ela mesma ou outra função a fim de fazer um "loop", para fazer uma basta você colocar uma condição de saída dentro de uma função e depois chama-la recursivamente, até que a condição seja atingida.
Exemplo, vamos supor que você deseja fazer uma função de multiplicação recursiva, então ela ficaria de tal maneira.

```
int multiplicaNumero ( int x, int y )
{
    if ( y <= 1)        /*  Condição de saída   */
        return x;

    return x + multiplicaNumero(x, y - 1);
}
```

Explicado isso, se você ter entendido o que eu expliquei, ficará facil de entender como fazer o seu exercício, então sem mais delongas, aqui está o resultado final da sua pergunta, essa seria a resposta que eu consideraria certa, dada a pergunta, lembrando que existe milhares de formas de se fazer a mesma coisa em C, então qualquer coisa perto disso seria correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somarPar ( int vet[], int tam )
{
    int* ptrVet = (int*)(vet), soma = 0;

    if ( tam <= 0 )
        return 0;

    if ( *ptrVet % 2 == 0 )
        soma = *ptrVet;

    return soma + somarPar((int*)(ptrVet + 1), tam - 1);
}

int main ()
{
    int vetor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int tam = sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(vetor[0]);

    printf("a soma dos numeros pares eh: %i\n", somarPar(vetor, tam));

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado ;), boa sorte com os estudos na linguagem C.

Comment: Eu acho que fica mais bonito e direto ao assunto de ponteiros se na assinatura de `somaPar` você por como primeiro argumento `int *vet` no lugar de `int vet[]`

Comment: E eu concordo plenamente com você, a questão é que este é o código dela e não o meu entende, então eu meio que tentei fazer do jeito que ela faria, que consequentemente seria o melhor jeito dela entender, então você pode repara que eu deixo a função do mesmo jeito que foi a que ela passou para a gente.

Answer (score 1):

O código tem vários problemas, alguns de sintaxe.

Na verdade considero o exercício ruim para recursividade. Ele fica melhor com iteração.

Tanto que parece que estava colocando um laço dentro da função recursiva.

Não vi necessidade de uso de ponteiros neste algoritmo.

Precisa ter uma condição de encerramento da recursividade (`n > 0`) e a condição simples se é par e deve pegar este valor ou não.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somarpar(int vet[], int n) {
    return n > 0  ? somarpar(vet, n - 1) + (vet[n] % 2 == 0 ? vet[n] : 0) : 0;
}

int main(void) {   
    int vetor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    printf("a soma dos numeros pares eh: %i\n", somarpar(vetor, 10));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1F3E4w). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ypsnqbym-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumOddRecursive.c).